# How to have memory/cpu limits only for forked children and not for the parent process?

Tags: linux, systemd, apache-httpd, memory, cgroups

Is there a way to have limits for (let's say) apache2, that limits each forked child worker process to use max X memory, and not the entire process tree (apache2 and all of its forked children) to max X memory?

I have tried solutions with cgroups/systemd but everything limits the main process and all of its children combined, and not each child individually.

I am looking for a solution not only for apache2 but for all processes that spawn children.

Comment: As I try to explain, what you want to do is nearly impossible, and certainly unreasonable, if you want a systematic solution

Comment: Smells a big lot  like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the actual concern that you really have. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/512558/edit) your question to motivate it and give much more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just improve the source code of your application (maybe Apache2 in your case, which is open source) to call [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) after the successful call to [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), but before the call to [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

Because you really want to have the `setrlimit` system call done *after* the `fork` (what you have then set remains till some further call to `setrlimit`, perhaps by the `ulimit` builtin of your shell).

Take some time to understand better how Linux [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) work (in particular [`fork`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) & `execve` & `setrlimit`) and how and when you should use them. I recommend reading a good Linux system programming book, such as [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

Therefore, what you want to achieve is not realistic in general, unless you accept to change slightly every program you are using.  The [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) which inspired the design of `fork`, `execve` , `setrlimit`  forbids that.

Of course, you could in principle do insane [`LD_PRELOAD` tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426230/841108) to overload the behavior of `fork` (calling `setrlimit` after it returns 0) or of `execve` (calling `setrlimit` syscall before it) for [dynamically linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (or equivalently, patch your own variant of `libc.so`), but that is not reasonable. See also [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) or [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) to detect such dynamically linked executables.

You could however use the `ulimit` shell builtin to put limits on Apache2 and all its children. And you might dive into Apache2 documentation, it has tons of settings regarding its child processes.

Comment: Although this may work for apache2 I don't think editing the source code of every process that spawns children is an achievable task.